# IIS web.config Active Directory Windows Authentication using roles works for AD user but not AD group or Local Group

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to ultimately get Windows Auth to work in my web.config using local groups on the windows web server.  Here is my issue...

I have the following test virtual env. setup

Windows 2019 AD DNS DC
Windows 2012 R2 Webserver, named testweb
domain is "test.local" netbios name of "test"
domain user is "test\testuser1"
domain group that testuser1 belongs to is "testgroup1", security group not a distb group btw
local group on testweb called "localgroup1" that "test\testuser1" belongs to.. "test\testuser1" is also part of the local administrators group on testweb

Here is my web.config

```
 <system.web>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>

    <authentication mode="Windows" />  

    <authorization>
      <allow roles="test\testuser1"/>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
   </system.web>
```

this works perfectly and i can auth to my default.asxp page. if i change it to

```
<authorization>
          <allow roles="test\testuser2"/>
          <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
       </system.web>
```

then of course i get denied access as i expect because I am not logged in as testuser2
I then change it to the following..

```
<authorization>
          <allow roles="test\testgroup1"/>
          <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
       </system.web>
```

but get access denied even though "test\testuser1" belongs to the security group testgroup1.. i would expect since i'm logged in with testuser1 it should work.

then i say let me try a local group on testweb server. which again IS my ultimate goal is to use a local group

```
<authorization>
          <allow roles=".\localgroup1"/>
          <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
       </system.web>
```

when i do this, it works!! BUT, here is the BUT it works LOL whether or not "test\testuser1" is a member of the local group "localgroup1" or NOT!!! which is strange..

so i can't seem to 1st get AD groups even working and 2nd my local groups just let me through no matter if my test\testuser1 account is in the local group or not :(

so at this point i'm totally confused and frustrated on what is not going right with getting roles working with either AD Groups or Local Groups, again my goal is to have it work with Local Groups

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create a new Group in Locals User Group in Computer Management and add the AD group there. and then add the local group in iis authorization rule. also, check that in iis site windows authentication is enabled and the rest of the are disabled.

[image]

add code in your web.config as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>        
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Allow" roles="MyDomain\SomeADGroup" />
                <add accessType="Deny" users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: i tried your method and still same things happen based on all the evidence i presented before. my user gets denied access even though i have the user in the AD group or the local group

Answer (score 0):

IIS: Setting it in ".NET Authorization rules" and restarting app pool results in Web.config having this key and it works (given that group has permissions in application folder):

```
<allow roles="localgroupname"/>
```